# Two living things

Tags: word

We are two living things. Part of one of us is another living thing. Another part of one of us is something all people use. One part of one of us contains motion and another part of one of us contains action. Another part of one of us, read backwords, has a philosophical meaning. Who are we?

Comment: Are the two things connected in some way other than both being living things?

Comment: Both are mammals.

Answer (score 1):

It would not surprise me if this question has multiple possible answers, but here is one:

You are a

> GOAT and a WATER STRIDER

Part of one of us is another living thing.

> 'OAT' is part of 'GOAT' and is a type of living plant.

Another part of one of us is something all people use.

> Things like 'hand', 'eye', 'foot' are ruled out as not all people have/can use them.  Likely candidates are 'brain', 'mind', 'air', and 'water'.  In this case, 'WATER' is part of 'WATER STRIDER'.

One part of one of us contains motion

> 'STRIDE' is part of 'WATER STRIDER'; STRIDE is strongly associated with motion.

and another part of one of us contains action.

> 'GO' is part of 'GOAT' and is strongly associated with action.

Another part of one of us, read backwards, has a philosophical meaning.

> 'TAO' is part of 'GOAT' (backwards) and is a word from Philosophical studies (in Chinese philosophy, the absolute principle underlying the universe)

Comment: It feels like, with the way it's presented, that the two things should have a stronger connection in some way. I know it's not explicitly stated but it would seem odd if this were not the case, I will clarify with the OP.

Comment: rot13(znlor TBNG & QBAXRL, rirelbar hfrf xrlf, QB vf npgvba)